# Node.js: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined (nested query)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update a field in a MongoDB collection which has nested documents. I have to increase a certain value. The update query works just fine, but I need to nest it in another query where I get the current value, so I could increase it.

The nesting worked just fine when I used a faulty `find()` method. I realized I must use `aggregate()`. I can't get it working, the method returns undefined for some reason. I've tried the same aggregate query in the shell and it works, so it has to do something with the Node.js

The function that fails:

```
static addPointsToUser(mainId, userId, pointsToAdd) {
  const db = getDb();

  function getCurrent() {
    db.collection('mycoll')
      .aggregate([
        { $match: { _id: mainId } },
        { $unwind: '$userPoints' },
        { $match: { 'userPoints._id:': userId } },
        { $group: { _id: 'userPoints._id', userPoints: { $push: '$userPoints.points' } } }
      ])
  }

  function updateNew(newPoints) {
    db.collection('mycoll')
      .updateOne(
        { _id: mainId },
        { $set: { "userPoints.$[elem].points": newPoints } },
        {
          multi: true,
          arrayFilters: [{ "elem._id": userId }]
        }
      )
  }

  return getCurrent()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      const newPoints = result.userPoints[0];
      return updateNew(newPoints)
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result);
          return result;
        })
    })
}
```

The document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5d4048f56a895612acabe0a9"),

  // Some other fields

  "userPoints": [
    { "_id": "manualID1", "points": 80 },
    { "_id": "manualID2", "points": 90 }
  ]
}
```

Expected aggregate result:

```
{ "_id" : "manualID1", "userPoints" : [ 90 ] }
```

Mongo shell gives the result seen above.

Actual result:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

If I log the aggregate result it prints and empty array ( [] ).

Comment: Probably read the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/index.html https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Answer (score 5):

Your methods `getCurrent` and `updateNew` are not returning anything. Which mean you are using `.then()` on something which is *undefined* as stated by your error message.

Adding a `return` statement before `db.collection('mycoll')` should help you with that.

Comment: Now I've got a `TypeError: getCurrent(...).then is not a function` error

Comment: You should check your database doc to make sure the `.aggregate` method is returning a `Promise`. Judging from your error it might not be the case.